# Code First Join options in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework

I'm creating a webservice layer over a legacy SQL Server based system.  It's a pretty large and complicated business application which has a large number of stored procedures that perform SELECT statements .  Most of these stored procedures join a number of tables and produce a single resultset for easy consumption by the client.

In building my webservice I want to take advantage of EF, and using a Code First approach 80% of my use cases can be achieved by mapping direclty to tables.  However I have a number of use cases where  I need the cross tbale views of data as provided by the stored procedures.  As I see it I have 3 options:

1. Create new POCOs that represent the stored procedure returns and link these to the existing stored procedures (let SQL do the join and re-use exisitng code)
2. Create new POCOs that look like the stored procedure return, but populate themselves by association with othe EF entities (let EF do the jons)
3. Do the joins somehow in LINQ

What do people think is best practice in situations like this, which I guess most of us are coming up against everyday?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

many a good book out there.     anything from Julie Lerman...    this is more recent http://www.apress.com/9781430257882

With Navigation properties, you can do most things without old fashioned joins.

**So 4) do it in Linq,and let EF do the Joins.** 
  Use Navigation properties. you can do many logical joins and even avoid the join keyword.

this blog shows how easy and why LINQ with no join syntax  results in Joins at the db level.
http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first